# what's up with u-law companding when u is 0

Tags: communication

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/principles_of_communication/principles_of_communication_modulation_techniques.htm

It says that I can get the compressed output of a signal using this:

[image]

it also says that there is no compression when u=0...
when I plug it in the formula it should give me back my input but instead I end up dividing 0 by 0...

can someone please help me understand why this has been a long running thing in data communication?

Comment: Are you familiar with l'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: apply limit u->0 and  solve

Comment: Also apply L'hospital's rule twice.

Comment: oh right there's that... thanks